# Apps Script - Find Images between 2 Headings/Bookmarks in Google Doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm creating a script that will copy data from a sample input doc to the sample output doc

My sample input doc is a brochure of products, with each product having:

- A Heading **(which is bookmarked)**
- A table cell with some data
- Multiple inline images

> [Image of Sample Input Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onYXR.png)

My sample output doc is a summarised version of the sample input doc. It will output a single table cell for each product containing:

- The text of the heading
- The first image of the product **(In the sample input doc, the image is
  highlighted in red)**
- Bookmark link of the heading in the sample input doc

> [Image of Sample Output Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3UnN.png)

I will add the link to the [sample input doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FpKaAjWs2JGGCauVUPLs5yGOfITM8olQArdETywmD_8/edit?usp=sharing) and [sample output doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lyL9m3hr9oWOyylAvCU0HWZl6uiOaNqWSwWzx7xZA48/edit?usp=sharing) for reference:

I can successfully copy the text of the heading and the bookmark link. However I am struggling to find the images that are under a Heading. In production, the images in the first doc are copied from the internet and pasted into the doc. I believe I can get the blob of the inline image but I just don't know how to identify which images belong to a heading?

I would truly appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction in isolating the images that are under a heading

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In your question, "first doc" and "second doc" are the sample input and the sample output situations you expect, respectively? If my understanding is correct, can I ask you about the situation of the sample output situation before your expected script is run? And, can you provide your current script? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Are you looking for inlineImages or postionedImages.  Only inlineImages url

Comment: @Cooper I am looking for inlineImages

Comment: @Tanaike Yes you are correct, 'First Doc' and 'Second Doc' are my sample input and output to demonstrate what I want to achieve. What I'm expecting is to get a list of images that are under a heading, from there I will be able to pass the url of the image to the sample output

Comment: HeaderSection has a method getImages() [Class InlineImage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/inline-image)

Comment: @Cooper I am not referring to the header of a page, I'm referring to the headings used in a paragraph or body of text i.e. Heading1 just like the example above

Comment: You can just get the number of children from the body class and then each child will be an element of a given type.  You should be able to figure the rest out on your own

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `@Tanaike Yes you are correct, 'First Doc' and 'Second Doc' are my sample input and output to demonstrate what I want to achieve. What I'm expecting is to get a list of images that are under a heading, from there I will be able to pass the url of the image to the sample output`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? Before I prepare an answer, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Cooper Oh okay, I will try the approach you suggested, thank you!

Comment: @Tanaike I'm not sure what else to say other than I'm trying to get all the images that are under a Heading, please do refer to the sample input and output for what I'm trying to explain. Your suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Tanaike Do you have any suggestions for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
function findInLineImages() {
  const body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  const stype = DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH;
  const sheading = DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1;
  var loc = null;
  var idxA = [];
  var locA = [];
  var idx;
  do {
    loc = body.findElement(stype, loc);
    locA.push(loc)
    if (loc) {
      let par = loc.getElement().asParagraph();
      if (par.getHeading() == sheading) {
        idx = body.getChildIndex(loc.getElement());
        idxA.push(idx);//heading child indexes
        Logger.log('Heading Text: %s type: %s idx: %s',par.getText(),loc.getElement().getType(),idx)
      }
    }
  } while (loc != null)
  var iloc = locA[0];
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(idxA[0].toString()))
  do {
      iloc = body.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE,iloc);
      if(iloc) {
        let img = iloc.getElement().asInlineImage();
        idx = body.getChildIndex(iloc.getElement().getParent());
        let h = img.getHeight();
        let w = img.getWidth();
        if(idx < idxA[1]){
          Logger.log("child index: %s width: %s height: %s",idx,w,h)
        }
        
      }
  }while(iloc != null && idx < idxA[1])
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggested code above, I'm confused as how this iterates over each heading. When I run the code, it only seems to iterate and print the images in the first heading, but not the successive headings? I was thinking of using a for loop for idxA but I'm not too sure

Comment: In my example I assumed there was a first heading and a last heading and I was only looking for the images between the two. If that was not your intended process then I apologize for my misunderstanding. If you wish to pursue this further I would appreciate further information to explain your requirements so that I can provide you with a better example.

Comment: Not at all, I should apologise for not clearly elaborating on my intentede process. I have edited my original question above to include my requirements and hopefully it makes sense. I sincerely thank you for taking the time to guide me through this process

Comment: Your assumption is not far off, I'm looking for the images in each heading as opposed to the images between the first and last heading. Your suggestions on how to improve the above code will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think you can take it from here.  I have some code that iterates through each child in the body and each child in a paragraph by using paragraph().asBody() to find the elements in each paragraphy,.  But the code I have is quite extensive and would not serve as an appropriate example for your question.  So I will leave it as an exercise for the reader.